# Update a specific column of a List <T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

First they forgive me for my English since it is not my native language.
I have a method which receives a generic list `List<T>`. what I want is to foreach through the whole list and be able to update a column called Eliminated  of each class `T` and which is of the boolean type, is it possible to do? can anybody help me.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Delete (Change status delete = true)
public void Delete<T>(List<T> data)
{      
    if (data != null)
    {
        data.ForEach(x =>
        {
           ...
        });
    }           
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't work because the method is generic and has no constraints. That means it could be called with any object, even with those which don't have a `Eliminated` or `Deleted` property.

Comment: Do you want a generic method to allow you to updated specific properties?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `T` i would use an interface, because otherwise in the `foreach` you cannot access the property `Eliminated`.

Here the interface:

```
interface IExample {

    bool IsEliminated { get; set; }    

}
```

and here the method with the `ForEach` loop.

```
public void Delete<T>(List<T> data) where T : IExample
{      
    if (data != null)
    {
        data.ForEach(x =>
        {
           x.Eliminated = true;
        });
    }           
}
```

Comment: This works very well for me, thank you very much! One last question after doing this process how can I update my table in my database with a simple `ContextDb.SaveChange();`

Comment: e.g. you can do this after each iteration in the `ForEach` loop - this works for small lists. Otherwise you have to do it after the `forEach` so that it is only called once.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a generic method to update a list of *any* type, you could do something like this:

```
public void Update<T>(List<T> data, Action<T> func)
{
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

    data.ForEach(func);
}
```

Note I've change the null check to throw if you pass in a null list. You could just return here instead, this way eliminates some nesting.

This allows you to pass in an action that you apply to every item in a collection. You would use it like this:

```
var data = new List<YourClass> = GetData();

Update(data, item => item.Eliminated = true);
```

Comment: And now i wonder why not simply: `foreach(var x in data) x.Eliminated = true;` and save a lot of code. What is the added value of this (and other answers)?

Comment: This works very well for me, thank you very much! One last question after doing this process how can I update my table in my database with a simple `ContextDb.SaveChange();`

Comment: @JonathanBurgosGio You just call `SaveChanges` like you would normally.

Answer (score 3):

Your `T` has no property called `Eliminated`. Your compiler cannot guarantee that *any* `T` you will ever use with this method will have that member, so you are not allowed to compile it that way.

You could put a constraint on your `T` that allows the compiler to make sure the property exists:

```
public interface Eliminatable
{
    bool Eliminated { get; set; }
}

public void Delete<T>(List<T> data) where T : Eliminatable
{      
    if (data != null)
    {
        data.ForEach(x => { x.Eliminated = true; });
    }           
}
```

Or (and some may say this is a hack) you can just trust your users that they *will* in fact pass something as `T` that confirms to your pattern:

```
public void Delete<T>(List<T> data)
{      
    if (data != null)
    {
        data.ForEach(x => { dynamic d = x; d.Eliminated = true; });
    }           
}
```

Now this will fail if the property is not there. At runtime. Not nice. But it "works".

Comment: good point with `dynamic` but I would normally not suggest to use it, because you lose a lot of type safety will runtime.

Comment: @KevinWallis Yes, I'm one of those who'd consider it "a hack". But it's an option.